# Parsing error: Identifier 'store' has already been declared. I am getting this error on my main.js and I am not sure how to go on about it

Tags: vue.js

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,
});
```

Heres the main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import App from "./App.vue";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firebase";
import { firestorePlugin } from "vuefire";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import "./assets/app.scss";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
import "video.js";
import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";
import "videojs-playlist-ui/dist/videojs-playlist-ui.vertical.css";
import "videojs-playlist-ui/dist/videojs-playlist-ui.css";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(firestorePlugin);

const firebaseConfig = {
  databaseURL: "https://trudeau-cda16.firebaseio.com/forum.json%22"

};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

export const db = firebase.firestore();

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  store.dispatch('fetchUser', user);
});


state = {
     notes: [],
     dates: [],
     counter: 0,
     tags: [
       'Important',
       'Must Check',
       'Imcomplete',
       'Done',
       'Revise',
       'Not Important',
     ],
     selectedTags: [],
  user: {
    loggedIn: false,
    data: null,
  },
};

 mutations = {
      ADD_NOTE(state, payload) {
        let newNote = payload;
        state.notes.push(newNote);
        state.counter++;
     },
      DELETE_NOTE(state, payload) {
       let index = payload;
       state.notes.splice(index, 1);
       state.dates.splice(index, 1);
       state.counter--;
     },
     ADD_DATE(state, payload) {
        let newTimeStamp = payload;
       state.dates.push(newTimeStamp);
     },
     ADD_TAG(state, payload) {
        let tag = payload;
       state.tags.unshift(tag);
     },
     ADD_SELECTED_TAG(state, payload) {
        let selectedTag = payload;
       state.selectedTags.push(selectedTag);
     },
  SET_LOGGED_IN(state, value) {
    state.user.loggedIn = value;
  },
  SET_USER(state, data) {
    state.user.data = data;
  },
};
```

```
actions = {
     addNote(context, payload) {
       context.commit('ADD_NOTE', payload);
     },
     deleteNote(context, payload) {
       context.commit('DELETE_NOTE', payload);
     },
     addDate(context, payload) {
       context.commit('ADD_DATE', payload);
     },
     addTag(context, payload) {
       context.commit('ADD_TAG', payload);
     },
     addSelectedTag(context, payload) {
       context.commit('ADD_SELECTED_TAG', payload);
     },
  fetchUser({ commit }, user) {
    commit('SET_LOGGED_IN', user !== null);

    if (user) {
      commit('SET_USER', {
        displayName: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
      });
    } else {
      commit('SET_USER', null);
    }
  },
};

  getters = {
  user: (state) => state.user,
     getNotes: state => state.notes,
     getDates: state => state.dates,
     getTags: state => state.tags,
     getSelectedTags: state => state.selectedTags,
     getNoteCount: state => state.notes.length,
     getCounter: state => state.counter,
};

var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,
});


new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  vuetify,
   computed: {
     notes() {
       return this.$store.getters.getNotes;
     },
     dates() {
       return this.$store.getters.getDates;
     },
     tags() {
       return this.$store.getters.getTags;
     },
     selectedTags() {
       return this.$store.getters.getTags;
     },
     counter() {
       return this.$store.getters.getCounter;
     },
   },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

I could not find anything online that would help me. I am quite new to js and im not trying out vue.

Comment: Could you add more description so others can understand?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're first creating a variable called store here

```js
import store from "./store";
```

So, when you try to create another variable called `store` later in the same file, it fails.

```js
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,
});
```

Either change the name of the import or the variable you assign your `vuex` store to.
Something like this

```js
var VuexStore = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,
});
```

Comment: i followed the steps and got 2 more errors. 1.'VuexStore' is assigned a value but never used.2.'Vuexstore' is not defined

Comment: You've written `Vuexstore` without a capital `S` (`Vuexstore` -> `VuexStore`), which is why the first one is never used and the 2nd is never defined.